# android flutter app development: bundletool Deploy APKs to a connected device

Tags: android, apk, bundletool

I developed a flutter app and have tested that it works through android studio. Now I am trying to install it through the built files.

Using bundletool, I have created a `my_app.apks`, and am trying to install it to my android device. The command I use is `java -jar bundletool.jar install-apks --apks=E:/code/custom-snooze-alarm/build/app/outputs/my_app.apks --device-id=8350926d`, though I don't understand the result.

Am trying to follow https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#deploy_with_bundletool but it's not clear on what I should expect. When it says `The APKs have been extracted in the directory: C:\Users\NICKTO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\8317355586216688313`, does this mean it was extracted into my local (windows) filesystem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The APKs are extracted in a temporary directory before they are installed on the device. If the command completes and you don't have an error message, then the app has been successfully installed. I guess a success message would be nice as well, but you should be able to find the app installed on the device once the command finishes.